# Get multiple values with brackets from rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have rows containing data like this in column called ERROR_CODE:

```
00111[2003] Maschine0; 000222[2003] Maschinen2
```

I need to filter out only values in the brackets like this in one row:
2003;2003

I have one solution but only to get first element. And I would need all of them...like 2003,2003

```
SUBSTRING(ERROR_CODE,CHARINDEX('[',ERROR_CODE)+1 ,CHARINDEX(']',ERROR_CODE)-CHARINDEX('[',ERROR_CODE)-1)
```

Could you pease help me to find a solution?

Comment: Is `'00111[2003] Maschine0; 000222[2003] Maschinen2'` one row, or 2? What is the result you are expecting for the above? 2 rows? 1 row, with an aggregated string? Are you errors always delimited by a semi colon (`;`)? Could a single delimited value have multiple values in brackets..?

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @eshirvana,@Larnu Sorry, I am using SQL Server v18.9.2. My expectation is to get the two values in brackets in one row separated by semicolon.

Comment: There is no SQL Server v18. The latest version is Version 15; SQL Server 2019.

Comment: The schema is bad. This cries out for an additional table.

Comment: 18.9.2 is Management Studio, not Sql Server itself. Giving us the management studio version is like telling us your car is made by Sony, because that's the brand you see on the dash radio.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: @lptr this is doing that I was wishing for, great!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on several assumptions:

1. Each error is semicolon (`;`) delimited
2. An error always contains **one** value in brackets (`[]`)
3. You are using a fully supported version of SQL Server.

One method to achieve this would be to string your string on the delimiter (`;`). Then you can find the position left bracket (`[`) and the right (`]`) and `SUBSTRING` to get the content between. Thing finally you can string aggregate to get 1 row (per value of your column) again:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(V.YourColumn,CI.LB +1, CI.RB - CI.LB - 1),',')
FROM (VALUES('00111[2003] Maschine0; 000222[2003] Maschinen2'))V(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(V.YourColumn,';') SS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('[',V.YourColumn),CHARINDEX(']',V.YourColumn)))CI(LB,RB)
GROUP BY V.YourColumn;
```

For point 3, if you are not using a fully supported version of SQL Server you will need to use a user defined (set based or CLR) string splitter and `FOR XML PATH` respectively for splitting and aggregating your strings. If either 1 and 2 are not true, you have a far more fundamental problem with your design that your let on; fix your design.